# what are the different format options for importing a file in MSAccess

Tags: sql, ms-access, file-import

I am using MSAccess and am using this code

```
[Text;HDR=''No'';FMT=''Delimited'';Database='+ExtractFilePath(Location)+'].'+ ExtractFileName(Location);
```

What are the different options I can use for FMT? I have seen:

1. Fixed
2. Delimited
3. TabDelimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODBC Text Driver supports the following formats:
Tab Delimited
CSV Delimited
Custom Delimited
Fixed-Length